# Adding Parse to iOS App Errors

Tags: xcode, facebook, parse-platform

I'm trying to incorporate Parse into my iOS app.  After adding all the Frameworks and building the app I get several error messages none being related to the code itself.

[image]

I read somewhere that you need to add the Facebook SDK to your project and I did that but it only took away 3 of the errors.  Does anybody know the proper instructions on installing the Facebook SDK to your project?  Perhaps I didn't add it correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need Facebook to compile a project with Parse SDK

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Swift?

I had the same problem and it was because the frameworks are in Obj-C.

If that's the case, you need to add a bridge header file - here's a quick overview of how to do so: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/building-apps-with-parse-and-swift/

Here's the content of my bridge header file:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>
#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
```

Comment: I'm using Objective-C not Swift.  :(

Comment: Ah - ok. Those errors looked exactly the same as mine.

Here's FB guide on SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started